# Criar listview com dados do banco e colocar um EditText na frente de cada informação

Tags: android, listview, dialog

preciso criar uma listview dentro de um dialog, usando os dados do banco SQLite, mas em cada um dos dados que vai carregar tem que ter um EditText na frente, por exemplo.

Produto     Quantidade
Adubo       EditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após criar sua listagem normalmente (dados e adapter), basta inserí-los no dialog. Algo como:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.my_list, null, false);

        // Listagem normal: recuperar ListView, dados do banco, criar adapter que terá seu próprio layout (com o EditText e os TextViews) para os dados

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Título")
                .setMessage("Mensagem")
                .setView(view);
                  .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          //TODO
                      }
                  })
                  .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);

        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }

}
```

Comment: André, deu certo, obrigado !

Comment: Boa @AlexwellSouza !